# Check that a relational expression is true for all complex numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

How can I use *Mathematica* to check if a statement like $$\left| \frac{\sqrt{1+2z}-2}{2z-3} \right| \le 1$$ is true for all complex numbers $z$?

Also, how can I use *Mathematica* to check such a statement for a subset of the complex numbers (for example, all complex numbers with imaginary part less than zero)?

Comment: For `z==3/2` it's undefined

Comment: @Belisarius supposedly the OP would consider the limit of the `0/0` expression, which is `1/4`. For the OP: by simplifying `(Sqrt[1 + 2z] - 2)/(2z - 3) /. z -> x + I y` and going back to `z` you'll get `Abs[Sqrt[1 + 2z] + 2] ≥ 1`. Is this easier fro you to tackle?

Comment: Oh, the above expression is just an arbitrary example of a relational expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Resolve[Exists[z, Abs[(Sqrt[1 + 2 z] - 2)/(2 z - 3)] > 1], Complexes]
(*
False ... after a few looong minutes
*)
```

**Edit**

*Slightly* faster:

```
Reduce[FullSimplify[Abs[(Sqrt[1 + 2 z] - 2)/(2 z - 3)]] <= 1, z, Complexes]
```

**Edit 2**

*Much* faster:

See that:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(Sqrt[1 + 2 z] - 2)/(2 z - 3)]]
(*
 1/Abs[2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 z]]
*)
```

So:

```
Reduce[FullSimplify[(2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 z]) Conjugate[2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 z]]] > 1, z, Complexes]
(*
  True
*)
```

Comment: Whoa, that takes quite a bit longer than what I was hoping for. Is there any faster way?

Comment: @DavidZhang See my edit 2

Comment: FullSimplify[(2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 z]) Conjugate[2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 z]] > 1] evalutes to true as well, but much faster